# Internet sporadically dropping only on Ubuntu machines

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, vpn, openvpn

I'm having issues with all my Ubuntu machines. The internet connection will sporadically drop for a few minutes and it happens frequently like every 5-10 min. It will reconnect on it's own or I can reboot my Google Nest Wifi mesh and the internet will reconnect that way too. Meanwhile I have internet on my phone and other devices. I looked at `sudo watch netstat -tulnep` and I see that my Nordvpn which is using `openvpn` will have a very high number in the `Send-Q` column. Usually when that number is very high that's when my internet stops working. After that number goes down to 0 the internet works again. I have no clue what's causing this or how to even fix it. Would appreciate any help with this, thank you.

My ISP is Verizon Fios and I have this issue on Wifi and wired connection. It makes no difference if I'm connecting to wifi from my mesh network or from the Verizon router. Both the laptop and desktop are running `20.04.1-Ubuntu` kernel release `5.13.0-28-generic` and airplane mode is off.

Here's my ifconfig before connecting to vpn:

```
br-ccc1c02cedb8: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:7dff:fe70:cf39  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:7d:70:cf:39  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 734  bytes 779426 (779.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 897  bytes 142075 (142.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp110s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.182  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 80:fa:5b:63:b3:72  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1256347  bytes 1736731001 (1.7 GB)
        RX errors 727  dropped 0  overruns 727  frame 0
        TX packets 324663  bytes 52749976 (52.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 54424  bytes 8231085 (8.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 54424  bytes 8231085 (8.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and ifconfig after connecting to vpn:

```
br-ccc1c02cedb8: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        ether 02:42:7d:70:cf:39  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 734  bytes 779426 (779.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 897  bytes 142075 (142.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp110s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.182  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 80:fa:5b:63:b3:72  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1258324  bytes 1738613517 (1.7 GB)
        RX errors 738  dropped 0  overruns 738  frame 0
        TX packets 325864  bytes 53002270 (53.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 55408  bytes 8332617 (8.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 55408  bytes 8332617 (8.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.23  netmask 255.255.0.0  destination 10.8.0.23
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 190  bytes 62389 (62.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 279  bytes 41366 (41.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

In the meantime the only thing I can do to solve this problem is restart the router.

After doing `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager` as `@waltinator` suggested I get this output:

```
-- Logs begin at Tue 2021-11-23 16:13:14 EST, end at Mon 2022-02-07 13:44:38 EST. --
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.4101] NetworkManager (version 1.22.10) is starting... (for the first time)
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.4102] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (ru>
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.4241] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.4381] manager[0x564b4c7c1030]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.4382] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5558] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5558] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "Sky-X4C"
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5561] dns-mgr[0x564b4c7ae290]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=symlink, plugin=systemd-resolved
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5569] rfkill0: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.4/0000:71:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill0) (driver iwlwifi)
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5576] manager[0x564b4c7c1030]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5577] manager[0x564b4c7c1030]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5612] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5639] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5655] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5668] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5674] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5676] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5677] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5678] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5678] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5694] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5694] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5694] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <warn>  [1644243857.5696] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5813] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5815] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5822] manager: (enp110s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5837] settings: (enp110s0): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1'
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5855] device (enp110s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.5999] device (wlp113s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.6003] manager: (wlp113s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.6012] device (wlp113s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <warn>  [1644243857.8021] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.8075] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.8078] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.8078] device (wlp113s0): supplicant interface state: init -> starting
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.8827] sup-iface[0x564b4c7d5920,wlp113s0]: supports 5 scan SSIDs
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.8830] device (wlp113s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.8831] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp113s0 created
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.8833] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp113s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.8835] device (p2p-dev-wlp113s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.8840] device (p2p-dev-wlp113s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243857.8842] device (wlp113s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 07 09:24:17 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <warn>  [1644243857.8859] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
Feb 07 09:24:20 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243860.8056] policy: auto-activating connection 'My Router' (b91f71e2-d4f5-4854-8a55-c7f5ecc659da)
Feb 07 09:24:20 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243860.8059] device (wlp113s0): Activation: starting connection 'My Router' (b91f71e2-d4f5-4854-8a55-c7f5ecc659da)
Feb 07 09:24:20 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243860.8060] device (wlp113s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 07 09:24:20 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243860.8062] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Feb 07 09:24:20 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243860.8064] device (wlp113s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 07 09:24:20 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243860.8066] device (wlp113s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'My Router' has security, but secrets are required.
Feb 07 09:24:20 Sky-X4C NetworkManager[1436]: <info>  [1644243860.8066] device (wlp113s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

Comment: I'm having / I had a comparable experience, on - currently - Ubuntu 20.04.3 desktop, but only in the recent months. I'm in Europe and connect via an LTE-modem (mobil-internet) wifi hotspot. So in the recent months my internet seemed to last like half-an-hour - 50 minutes at a time, after that cutting off. When it happens / happened, I fixed it by activating and deactivating airplane mode (I guess it's similar to restarting networking). Apropos, please indicate the exact Ubuntu versions on the impacted machines, possibly even with kernel versions (retrieved by `uname -r`) included...

Comment: @Levente I added the info, but I suspect for me it's an issue with the vpn service messing things up. I don't have this issue on any other device in the house android, windows, mac, etc.

Comment: Look at the logs! `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Have you tried setting a static IP on both your router for your Ubuntu computer and also for your computer in your Ubuntu settings?

Comment: @mchid No, I haven't done that. Wouldn't that defeat the point of using a vpn since I'm changing to a static IP?

Comment: @waltinator I added the logs, but not sure how much it will help.

Comment: Read the log, a line-by-line description of what various components of network startup. One important message is `Activation: (wifi) access point 'My Router' has security, but secrets are required.`, which says that your router (`MyRouter`) wants some authentication that you're not providing.

Comment: @waltinator I put in my router password. What else is there to provide? Maybe the vpn is tripping it up?